# Insert node key and value in binary search tree using scheme

Tags: scheme, racket, binary-search-tree

I am inserting a key `key` and a value `val` into the tree-map `t` returning a new tree with a node containing the key and the value in the appropriate location.

I have this defined:

```
(define (tree-node key value left right)(list key value left right))

(define (get-key tn) (node_key tn))
(define (get-val tn) (node_val tn))
(define (get-left tn) (node_left tn))
(define (get-right tn) (node_right tn))

(define (node_key tn) (list-ref tn 0))
(define (node_val tn) (list-ref tn 1))
(define (node_left tn) (list-ref tn 2))
(define (node_right tn) (list-ref tn 3))
```

Im trying this `insert` method

```
(define (insert t key val)

  (cond (empty? t))
  (tree-node (key val '() '()))

  ((equal key (get-key t))
   (tree-node (key val (get-left t) (get-right t)))

   ((<key (get-key t))
    (tree-node ((get-key t) (get-val t) (insert (get-left t key val)) (get-right t)))
    (tree-node ((get-key t) (get-val t) (get-left t) (insert (get-right t key val)))))))
```

I'm using this to define

```
(define right (insert (insert empty 3 10) 5 20))
```

and I'm getting this error in DrRacket

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: (list 0 1 2)
arguments...: [none]
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that a tree-node (which is just a list) is being returned in a position where a function is expected.  Scheme cannot execute the list - it's not a function, so it's complaining.

I suspect this is because you have messed up your parentheses.

```
(cond (empty? t))
```

Is a self-contained compound expression.  It is evaluated, returning the value of t.  The expressions after that are not evaluated as part of the cond.

Comment: Lot of syntax errors here.  The use of tree-node in the code is also syntactically dubious.  The author needs to make sure to pass four arguments.  At the moment, the code expresses that it is giving it a single argument.  Calling a function in this class of language is *(function arg1 arg2 ...)*, not *function(arg1 arg2 ...)*

Comment: I'm reindented the original poster's question.  The indentation levels should make it clear that the program structure is screwy.  The things that belong in the `cond` are outside of the `cond`, for example.